# Spring Boot + Quartz + Postgresql 9.4

Tags: spring, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler

I am using Spring Boot + Quartz + Postgresql 9.4

For initializing Quartz tables, I have wrote all sql scripts related to Quartz in data.sql which Spring boot automatically reads and run file in every restart.

### data.sql

```
drop table if exists qrtz_fired_triggers;
drop table if exists qrtz_paused_trigger_grps;

create table qrtz_job_details ...
create table qrtz_triggers....
...
...
create index idx_qrtz_j_req_recovery ...
create index idx_qrtz_j_grp ...
```

### application.properties

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

With this configuration, Table is created successfully.
Now if I create a job with 15 minutes from now, job will be successfully saved in quartz table.
At this point if server is restarted, all tables of quartz will be dropped and recreated because `"data.sql"` will run again and all future jobs will be deleted because of drop script in `data.sql`

I want to keep my quartz table and all jobs intact.
What should be best approach to solve this problem, I am using postgresql 9.4, so problem is i can't use `create index if not exist`

Approach I am thinking

### Approach 1

Logically creates table and index after application starts.

### Approach 2

I keep my jobs in Quartz table as well as in my schedule table, so upon restart my schedule table is intact as it is mapped to java entity, so read jobs from schedule table upon restart and create the jobs in quartz table again.

I would like to know the best approach.

Comment: Can you decouple application deployment and sql execution? Meaning you execute the sql first and then deploy the app?